# How to update a single element in mongodb

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

```
$http.put('/api/datas/' + val[$rootScope.id]._id,val[$rootScope.id].values[0].quantity =$scope.ass);
```

Above mentioned is the code where `val[$rootScope.id]._id` is the id of the field in mongodb and `val[$rootScope.id].values[0].quantity` is the quantity which is to be updated and `$scope.ass` is the updated value.

How can I update quantity value on MongoDB ?

Comment: Hi Akshay; I'm not quite sure I understand your question. Are you wondering how to design a suitable api endpoint through which a user can update the database? Or maybe you already have an api, and you are wondering if you're constructing your api call correctly? Or you want to implement the api back end, with the call to the database to update the value? If you could [edit] your question to clarify, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code for update database value :

```
db.databaseName.update(
   { _id: value_of_ID},
   {
       quantity : value_of_quantity;
   },
   { upsert: true }
)
```

Comment: I am doing it with angular because that's what my application needs.

Comment: So whats your actual needs ?

Comment: Please describe whats your actual need ?

Comment: I want to change the value of quantity which is stored in my database.The new value will be what is given by the user at that particular point of time in the text field

Comment: You need to update your value from backend. use my code in your backend , hopefully this code will solve your problem to update value.

Comment: You can check MongoDb documentation here : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-parameter